# What are these strange rays in the sky?

Tags: optics, visible-light, atmospheric-science, weather

While driving, I noticed the sky had weird rays that appeared converge at some point on the horizon.  I took a few pictures in hopes I could figure out what they were.  There was a storm coming from the other direction if that's relevant information.

[image: large image]
[image: small images]

They don't show up quite as well on the pictures, but they were definitely visible in real-life so not an artifact from the camera or anything.

Comment: Naive question: Did the point that they converged at happen to be in the direction of the sun, by any chance?

Comment: @Philip No, the sun was setting in a different section of the sky

Comment: was that different direction 180 degrees opposite?

Comment: @JEB I'm not sure how close to exactly 180 degrees, but it was definitely behind us while the rays were in front of us.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't appear to be about physics, it's just asking us to identify something.

Comment: @DavidZ Physics is the science of identifying things.  Nobel prizes have been awarded for "identifying things", like radiation, argon, the neutron, the CMB, and many others (dark matter someday?).  I think this is a great question which is helping make physics accessible to non-physicists, and it's a real shame that this SE is so closed-minded about what is and what is not physics.

Comment: @Yly No, that's not what physics is at all. I don't want to start a discussion here, but if you'd like to get into it further I'd encourage you to post on [meta] (or you could raise the topic in [chat] if you just want an idle discussion).

Comment: @DavidZ Literally the first bullet in the help center is "Explanations of observed physical or astronomical phenomena" which is exactly what is being asked.

Comment: Meta discussion is here: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13076/identifying-physical-phenomena-is-on-topic

Comment: @DavidStarkey It's important to include time-of-day, season, sun position, latitude in the question. In this case, not all matter, but we don't know that a priori. Had it been the zodiacal light, then spring/fall dusk/dawn northern/southern hemisphere all matter, for example.

Comment: This is the rising of the dark.

Comment: @DavidStarkey That is not what is being asked. This question doesn't ask to _explain_ anything at all.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Those are definitely [anticrepuscular rays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anticrepuscular_rays). The Sun was in the antipodes of the point of convergence of those rays in the sky, when you took that image. Here you have a similar observation:

[image]

These are formed just like crepuscular rays; [clouds in the direction of the Sun project parallel shadows](https://www.atoptics.co.uk/atoptics/rayform.htm) that [cross the entire sky over your head into the opposite direction](https://www.atoptics.co.uk/atoptics/skywide.htm) where the Sun was setting. You see them converging instead of being parallel because of the spherical projection of your spherical field of view (you can reinterpret this as the shadows are closer when they go over your head and are farther from you at the horizon so that rays that are parallel seem to converge at some point at infinity).

Comment: I wouldn't mix spherical projection into this discussion: the convergence of the rays happens even in the simple perspective projection, which is demonstrated by the photos on this page.